# QGIS - find specific numbered edge of a polygon

Tags: qgis

Is there a way within QGIS to find a specific numbered edge of a polygon? I'm running a shapefile through R, and `st_is_valid` reports `"Loop 0: Edge 263884 crosses edge 263886"` - how can I find those particular edges to rectify the problem?

The particular code in R that checks the validity is this simple block:

```
data <- st_read("shapefile_path.shp")
data <- sf::st_make_valid(data) #to fix problems r can just fix itself
st_is_valid(data, reason=TRUE)
head(data) #so I know which particular polygon st_is_valid is reporting an error with
```

Note that running QGIS's own Check Validity process results in no output to the resulting 'invalid' layer, so apparently QGIS doesn't consider this polygon invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The non-programmatic way to do that is to install the Topology Checker Plugin. then, Define a crossing rule. Then it will show you all the polygons that are invalid because of crossing.

If it doesn't work, I suppose to run a `simplify` processing on that layer with a very small tolerance value. The exported polygon should be fine. You can do the same with `polygonize` too.

Comment: Topology checker finds no problems with my polygons with a 'check invalid geometry' rule, which is the closest thing I can find to a 'crossing rule'. Besides, I know which polygon it is - I need to know *where* on its boundary the issue is, as it's a highly complex polygon and I can't just manually scan the outline and expect to find it.

Comment: Is it a self-intersecting polygon that raises the error?

Comment: I suppose to run a `simplify` processing on that layer with a very small tolerance value. The export should be fine. You can do the same with `polygonize` too.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. That seems to be the issue `st_is_valid` reports, but the error I get in R trying to use the shapefile may or may not suggest the same thing - it returns `Invalid number of points in LinearRing found 2 - must be 0 or >= 4`.

Comment: Ah, it's saying everything. Try the Topology Checker, but this time, add another rule of `must not have gaps` and `must not have multi-part` (only if your polygon must not have any multi-part). it should show you where's the bumpy part. But if you want a refined vector, try `simplify` or `polygonize` as I've addressed.

Comment: None of that is working, sadly, but as my original data seems to work fine with a different map projection, I suspect the issue is something unrelated. I've asked a somewhat different question over on StackOverflow now. Thanks for trying to help, though!